# First non demo example for Gaussian process using GPML (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression, gaussian, hyperparameters

After having some basics understanding of [GPML toolbox](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/) , I written my first code using these tools. I have a data matrix namely `data` consist of two array values of total size 1000. I want to use this matrix to estimate the GP value using GPML toolbox. I have written my code as follows :

```
x = data(1:200,1);    %training inputs
Y = data(1:201,2);  %, training targets 

Ys = data(201:400,2);   
Xs = data(201:400,1);    %possibly test cases


covfunc = {@covSE, 3}; 
ell = 1/4; sf = 1; 
hyp.cov = log([ell; sf]);
likfunc = @likGauss; 
sn = 0.1;
hyp.lik = log(sn);
[ymu ys2 fmu fs2] = gp(hyp, @infExact, [], covfunc, likfunc,X,Y,Xs,Ys);

plot(Xs, fmu);
```

But when I am running this code getting  error 'After having some basics understanding of [GPML toolbox](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/) , I written my first code using these tools. I have a data matrix namely `data` consist of two array values of total size 1000. I want to use this matrix to estimate the GP value using GPML toolbox. I have written my code as follows :

```
x = data(1:200,1);    %training inputs
Y = data(1:201,2);  %, training targets 

Ys = data(201:400,2);   
Xs = data(201:400,1);    %possibly test cases


covfunc = {@covSE, 3}; 
ell = 1/4; sf = 1; 
hyp.cov = log([ell; sf]);
likfunc = @likGauss; 
sn = 0.1;
hyp.lik = log(sn);
[ymu ys2 fmu fs2] = gp(hyp, @infExact, [], covfunc, likfunc,X,Y,Xs,Ys);

plot(Xs, fmu);
```

But when I am running this code getting:

> Error using covMaha (line 58) Parameter mode is either 'eye', 'iso',
>   'ard', 'proj', 'fact', or 'vlen'

Please if possible help me to figure out where I am making mistake ?

Comment: Do you honestly get "unknown error"?

Comment: I mean I am getting 'Error using covMaha (line 58)
Parameter mode is either 'eye', 'iso', 'ard', 'proj', 'fact', or 'vlen''  which is unknown to me. I am not referring to matlab.

Comment: Well, as you may understand, if you do not tell us what exactly MATLAB tells you it is going to be hard to help you. The fact that you do not understand it doesnt mean anyone else cant! (that is the reason why you are asking). Read [ask], and you may want to give a [mcve]

Comment: my apology, I modified the question , Please have a look and if possible suggest some solution.

Comment: Put the whole error stack please

Comment: Error using covMaha (line 58)
Parameter mode is either 'eye', 'iso', 'ard', 'proj', 'fact', or 'vlen'.

Error in covSE (line 21)
if nargin < 4, varargout{1} = covMaha(mode,par); return, end

Error in gp (line 85)
if eval(feval(cov{:})) ~= numel(hyp.cov)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144822/discussion-between-ander-biguri-and-ankita-debnath).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way late, but I just ran into this myself. The way to fix it is to change

```
covfunc = {@covSE, 3};
```

to something like

```
covfunc = {@covSE, 'iso'};
```

It doesn't have to be `'iso'`, it can be any of the options listed in the error message. Just make sure your hyperparameters are set correctly for the specific mode you choose. This is detailed more in the `covMaha.m` file in GPML.